# On coset equalities

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $H \le \textrm{Sym}(n)$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and Sym(n) stands for the symmetric group over $n$ elements. Furthermore let $g \in \textrm{Sym}(m)$ where $m \in \mathbb{Z} \land m \ge n$. This - I think - implies that $H \le \textrm{Sym}(m)$.

If we have $s = h_c g$ with $h_c \in H$, we can compute the left and right coset of $H$ in $\textrm{Sym}(m)$ with respect to $s$:
$$
sH = \{ s h | h \in H \} = \{ h_c g h | h \in H \}
$$
$$
Hs = \{ h s | h \in H \} = \{ h h_c g | h \in H \}
$$

I am now interested whether we can make statements about the equality of the produced left or right cosets that arise for a fixed $g$, but with arbitrary $h_c \in H$.

My thinking here was that given that $h h_c \in H$, the right cosets should always be identical, regardless of the chosen $h_c$.

For the left cosets on the other hand, I can't see a way to make any such statements in advance, without knowing anything about the chosen $g$.

My question is: Is my reasoning here correct or did I miss something?

---

The context here is that I have coded this up in a program, but the results I am seeing with that is the exact opposite of what I think I have derived using pen and paper. So before, I start digging in my program, I wanted to make sure my reasoning and understanding is correct.

Comment: @Devo ah sorry. I first formulated the question a bit differently and $G$ was a remnant of that. $G = Sym(m)$ - I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: If you are assuming that $H$ is a subgroup of ${\rm Sym}(n)$ (rather than just a subset) then you should write "Let $H \le {\rm Sym}(n)$".

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks for the correction. I have edited my post accordingly.